# Can it be a density for a bimodal distribution?

Tags: probability

I am curious about the density which contains the following item: $exp⁡(−(x-c)^4)$, where c is a constant. I know Generalized Normal Distribution contains the item but it can not be bimodal, right?

Can anyone provide some examples for bimodal distributions with densities containing the item above?

Comment: Check the critical points.  The derivative should be zero at one point: the maximum is at $x=c$ (the mode), which is also the mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right. A density function of shape $ke^{(x-c)^4}$ is like the normal except with  more sharply decreasing tails. A look at the function shows that it is symmetric about $x=c$, increases steadily in the interval $(-\infty,c]$ and then decreases. The mean, median, and mode are all at $x=c$.

For a bimodal distribution that has the component you seek, one can use
$k(x-c)^2 e^{-(x-c)^4}$ for suitable $k$. But there are many other possibilities.

Comment: maybe provide the names of some bimodal densities including the item I want? Thanks!

Comment: There is a list of bimodal distributions in Wikipedia. I doubt any of the standard ones will fit your $\exp(-(x-c)^4)$ condition. You can get something close, but with *two different* $c$'s by using a **mixture** of two generalized normals.